# Convergence almost surely - definition

Tags: probability, random-variables, set-theory

I am wondering if the below equations are equivalent?

$$P(\{\omega: \forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n\ge N \ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \varepsilon \}) = 1$$
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ P(\{\omega: \ \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n\ge N \ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \varepsilon \}) = 1$$
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \ P(\{\omega: \ \forall n\ge N \ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \varepsilon \}) = 1$$
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n\ge N  \ P(\{\omega: \ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \varepsilon \}) = 1$$

I tried to consider this set

$$\bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{n \ge N} \{ \omega:\ |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|< 1/k \}$$

and my attempt was to prove like this

My attempt was: let us take $\omega \in \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{n \ge N} \{ \omega:\ |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|< 1/k \}$. It means that $\omega$ is in the set $\bigcup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{n \ge N} \{ \omega:\ |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|< 1/k \}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then for all k, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\omega$ is in $\bigcap_{n \ge N} \{ \omega:\ |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|< 1/k \}$. And hence for all k, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge N$ $\omega$ is in $\{ \omega:\ |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|< 1/k \}$.

I don't know if this is correct. Please advsie.